# Речевые ошибки или нет?

Tags: лексика

Есть ли они во фразах, как вы считаете?

*Нельзя не отметить ряд особенностей, которые волнуют автора.

Иногда человек совершает неправильные, нехорошие действия.

Автор дает нам повествование жизни.

Совесть всегда будет ощущаться.*

Comment: Только второй пример нормальный.

Comment: oleedd,
а где ваши нормальные варианты?  Хотелось бы их увидеть.

Comment: Первое не знаю (специфический нюанс), а для остальных нужен контекст.

Comment: Лично я нашел во всех примерах для себя ошибки, поэтому и написал, чтобы посоветоваться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Редактирование текста**

1. *Следует отметить некоторые **особенные (конкретные) вопросы**, которые волнуют автора*.

Особенности не могут волновать.

2. *Иногда человек совершает неправильные, **недобрые** действия*.

Слово «нехороший» не сочетается со словом «неправильный», здесь нужна более точная и конкретная, а не общая оценка.

3. *Автор **предлагает нам** повествование **о жизни**.* Или: ***Это повествование** о жизни...*

Сочетание «повествование жизни» (1 пример в Нацкорпусе, 1814 год) по стилю выглядит архаично, лучше – повествование о жизни (8 примеров).

*Ввечеру того же дня князь Чистяков начал продолжать **повествование жизни** своей следующими словами* (В. Т. Нарежный. Российский Жилблаз, или Похождения князя Гаврилы Симоновича Чистякова, 1814).

Современный пример: Нам хотелось, чтобы книга читалась не как сборник, а как последовательное, непрерывное **повествование о жизни** трех замечательных людей (1997 год).

4. *Совесть всегда будет ощущаться как внутренний голос, **осуждающий злое и ведущий к добру.***

Предложение надо **как-то** распространить, иначе оно выглядит незаконченным.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139490/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon----).

Answer (score 1):

Смотря что считать речевыми ошибками...
Стилистические есть во всех фразах, и во второй тоже.
Конструкция "Совершает неправильные действия" весьма неуклюжа, если речь не идет о промышленном роботе со сбоящей программой

Answer (score 1):

*Совершает неправильные, нехорошие действия* — это разговорный вариант, он допустим (корректен). Не знаю, подходит ли разговорное для ЕГЭ, но разве стилистика изучается в школе полноценно? Более того: её нельзя изучить, это анализ и практика.

Совесть можно ощущать. Одно из значений "ощущать" — чувствовать. То есть чувствовать, что она есть.
Но стилистика — наука тонкая. В одних случаях оно звучит грамотно:
*Совесть всегда будет ощущаться [восприниматься] как внутренний голос, осуждающий злое и ведущий к добру.

Совесть всегда будет ощущаться как голос истины.*
а в других нет:
*Всегда ощущаю свою совесть.* || Изменена форма исходного примера. Здесь и "воспринимаю" не подходит. Исходный пример туда же.

Касательно первого примера. Авторы не говорят в статьях о своём волнении. Это относится к разговорному стилю. А нюанс с автором часто оформляется так:
*Автор данной статьи считает, что стоит отметить ряд особенностей.* || Просто показываю оформление (то есть через подлежащее).

Comment: С "правильным/неправильным" еще можно согласиться: такое в каких-то контекстах вполне может быть, но что значит "хорошее/нехорошее" действие ?

Comment: Смотрите: https://i.imgur.com/KIkf76R.png И там не зря сказано о множественном. Думаю, что единственное употреблять не стоит, а то не звучит.